# Definition of "trace_gpio_value" function in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, gpio

I'm reading the gpiolib.c code in the linux kernel to understand how the GPIO driver works. But I didn't find any definition of "trace_gpio_value" function.

```
trace_gpio_value(desc_to_gpio(desc), 0, value);
```

Anybody can help me about definition of trace_gpio_value?

Answer (score 1):

`trace_gpio_value()` and generally `trace_*()` are used by kernel `ftrace` static tracing utility to monitor some internals such as GPIO or networking (used for debugging and other purposes). These static tracing points cause collected data to be stored in a kernel buffer which you can see it's internals from tracing virtual file system mounted at */sys/kernel/tracing* if Kconfig option `CONFIG_FTRACE=y`. So, in a nutshell these trace points will act as a hook to call other tracing functions that you provide.

About the actual definition and how they work you must declare your tracing point using `DECLARE_TRACE()` in your header file. In your case check [*include/trace/events/gpio.h*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/trace/events/gpio.h) where you specify your tracing function and how it will work:

```c
#include <linux/tracepoint.h>
            # note the NAME (first_parameter)
TRACE_EVENT(gpio_value,
    ...<SNIP...>
);
```

NOTE: `TRACE_EVENT()` is a macro that gets expanded to `DECLARE_TRACE()`.

Then in your C code file you will add `trace_gpio_value()` whenever you want to trace and get the `gpio_value()` being called or another functions for another purposes.